# Directory Paths: Make them portable

Tags: directory

I got this warning status message. How can I fix this error? TIA[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi9eS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand messages like this can be worrisome but the msg actually tells you exactly what you need to fix the problem, eg it is suggesting you replace what you currently have set as the paths with the tokens shown. Try clicking on the 'Directories' link and then reading the help message that you will find there. If you need more help then paste a screenshot or the string in the 'paths' that you currently have, and someone will help coach you through which bits to replace with eg [cms.root]

Comment: this is related to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27332/settings-upload-directories

Comment: Hi again. Is this one is a major error or its just? Thanks.

Comment: It is a recommendation not an error - your site should still work with absolute paths - it is a recommendation because it makes it easier to move a site eg from dev to live