# Settings - Upload Directories

Tags: directory

I got this message when I go to this area? How to fix this error about civicrm.settings.php. TIA[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6yvs.png)

Comment: this is related to this https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27331/directory-paths-make-them-portable/27333#27333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the settings are hard coded in the civicrm.settings.php file in the sites/default/ directory on the server (the location may vary depending on your setup/CMS). You can manually remove the lines from the file that set the values.